# How to repeat animations with different coordinates

Tags: ios, swift, animation

I'm trying to animate labels to make them go to random coordinates again and again, but when I run, the animations don't process, even if I use a check variable to be sure the animation is complete before determinate other coordinates.
By the way, if you have any ideas to create interactions between labels, when they bump into each other, please, write it.

```
var check = 2
        var coordinateXLabel1 = 1
        var coordinateXLabel2 = 1
        var coordinateYLabel1 = 1
        var coordinateYLabel2 = 1
        while 1 == 1 {                     //create an infinit loop
            if check == 2{
                check = 0
                coordinateXLabel1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(324) + 25)
                coordinateXLabel2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(324) + 25)
                coordinateYLabel1 = Int(arc4random_uniform(560) + 111)
                coordinateYLabel2 = Int(arc4random_uniform(560) + 111)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                    self.label1.center = CGPoint(x: coordinateXLabel1, y: coordinateYLabel1)
                }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
                    check += 1
                })
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
                    self.label2.center = CGPoint(x: coordinateXLabel2, y: coordinateYLabel2)
                }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
                    check += 1
                })
            }
        }
```

Comment: where did you put this code (Didload?)

Comment: Keeping mind that in the time it would take to run a 1 second animation, your loop will queue many hundreds of animations. And none of them are setup to wait for any previous animation to finish.

Comment: This won't work as the while loop is blocking the UI thread of the whole application. Rather just perform the code once and restart the animation when both animations are done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code -

```
func animate()
{
    var coordinateXLabel1:Int = 1
    var coordinateYLabel1:Int = 1
    var coordinateXLabel2:Int = 1
    var coordinateYLabel2:Int = 1
    func animateLabel1()
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.label1.center = CGPoint(x: coordinateXLabel1, y: coordinateYLabel1)
        }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
            coordinateXLabel1  = Int(arc4random_uniform(324) + 25)
            coordinateYLabel1  = Int(arc4random_uniform(560) + 111)
            animateLabel1()
        })
    }
    func animateLabel2()
    {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: {
            self.label2.center = CGPoint(x: coordinateXLabel2, y: coordinateYLabel2)
        }, completion: {(finished:Bool) in
            coordinateXLabel2  = Int(arc4random_uniform(324) + 25)
            coordinateYLabel2  = Int(arc4random_uniform(560) + 111)
            animateLabel2()
        })
    }
    animateLabel1()
    animateLabel2()
}
```